# Transaction with Snapshot isolation gives inconsistent result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, transaction-isolation

Environment: SQL Server 2012

Backend: C# + EntityFramework

We use Change Tracking to obtain changes from multiple tables. All the operations are done inside one transaction with Snapshot isolation level. All queries inside that transaction are read-only.

```
using (var context = new BackendContext())
                {
                    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int count1= context.Reservation.Count();

                            //Then several read only operations to get changes from Chnage Tracking
                            ...

                            int count2= context.Reservation.Count();

                            if(count1 != count2)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Inconsistent state");
                            }

                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

So the first weird thing is that if we count number of rows in the table before processing of changes and after then sometimes we get different results. According to the MSDN: SNAPSHOT isolation specifies that data read within a transaction will never reflect changes made by other simultaneous transactions. But here inside one transaction with snapshot we get two different results.

Another major issue happens along with the one i just described above.

Inside that transaction we obtain changes from multiple tables.

Let's say we have Table1, Table2 and Junction table where we have one to many relationship so T1 row might have multiple T2 relations.

Sometimes it happens that we don't get changes from Table1 but we do have changes from Table2 with entries linked to Table1.
Again, everything happens inside one transaction with Snapshot isolation.

I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: I seem to remember that certain isolation levels were not supported by EF.

Comment: it's supported and this issues doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: is `Reservation` a table or a view?

Comment: it's a table but inside that transaction we also call stored procedures and functions. As far as i know all that calls should be inside the same transaction.

Comment: If it's possible to isolate traffic from one process, it'd be interesting to look at all of those statements through extended events to ensure they're all running in the same transaction. "Trust, but verify".

Comment: If these statements execute in the same transaction under snapshot isolation, they will yield the same counts. You can verify this in Management Studio. Ergo: they are *not* executing in the same transaction under snapshot isolation. I don't know enough about EF to say why not, but one approach that may have better success is to use `TransactionScope` rather than an explicit `.BeginTransaction`. Setting up a profiler trace to see what actually happens would also be invaluable.

Comment: We tried to use TransactionScope but it didn't help.

Comment: Then a profiler trace is your only remaining option (and/or whatever options EF has for tracing/logging, I know it has some). Either SQL Server has a nasty bug where somehow data integrity is violated or statements aren't executed the way you think they are because EF is doing something unexpected. The latter is a lot more likely than the former.